# How do i pass data from ejs(date picker) to js(to query db) and then display results back in ejs(in a label)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am a beginner to Nodejs/Mongo DB. I am working on designing a simple page where it displays Pass/Fail status for a chosen date in a button click.

I figured out how to query mongo DB collection to get the Pass and Fail values for a specific date(this 'date' has to come from html date picker).

So i am wondering how to make it dynamic, so that it works for any date chosen in datepicker.

Can someone please help? I have been struggling to find a solution.

```
**userlist.ejs**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Status</title>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Status</h1>
    <p>Welcome to Status</p>
    Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
    <input type="button" id="txbox" value="Find">
    <p>Pass is <%=userlist[0].Passed%></p>
    <p>Fail is <%=userlist[0].Failed%></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
index.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* GET Hello World page. */
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({
      $and: [
          {"Date": "29-03-2019"}
        ]
    },function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist" : docs
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

```
DB collection:
Collection name : usercollection
collection name - usercollection

{
Passed:"60"
Failed:"40"
Date: "30-03-2019"
}

{
Passed:"20"
Failed:"80"
Date: "29-03-2019"
```

As you can see i have harcoded date in mongo db query part - i want to replace it with a variable that can hold the value passed in date picker html(userlist.ejs). So how do i do this ?

My apologies if this sounds very noob!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're passing some data from client you need the `POST` http verb. To do that you need to `POST` from client and listen to post on server side. The following changes should help:

Use html `form` to post method (or you could use `AJAX` to post)

```
<form action="/userlist" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
  <button type="submit" id="txbox" value="submit"><Find<button>
</form>
```

In your router, you need to listen to `POST` request like:

```
router.post('/userlist', function(req, res) {
  // where did you get this?
  var db = req.db;

  // from html form, probably need some parsing
  var date = req.body.datepicker

  var collection = db.get('usercollection');
  collection.find({
    $and: [
      {"Date": date}
    ]
  },function(e,docs){
    res.render('userlist', {
      "userlist" : docs
    });
  });
});
```

Also you need to mount `body-parser` to parse the incoming form body

```
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

// app or server, whatever is your express, mount this before any routes
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```